# Eclipse Graphical Layout unable to display adView

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, adview

I updated from Eclipse Helios to Eclipse Juno, updated Android SDK tools to v23, and Google Play lib 4.4.

Since them i am unable to view XML layouts in eclipse Graphical Layout Window. I get following error.

```
Exception raised during rendering: com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

Error Log

```
Could not create the view: org.eclipse.pde.runtime.LogView
```

The error only shows when i add Google AdView XML in Layout, other wise Graphical Layout works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I still have a problem even change API to 19 based on a zhangxaochen's answer

I solve the problem after i Install JDK 1.7.

Java compiler in Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> compiler still use 1.6

Answer (score 1):

I bet you are using Java JDK 1.6.

**You have to go to Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler and set compiler to 1.7. Ofcourse you must have Java JDK 1.7 installed. If you don't, install it and the problem will dissappear.**

At least that was the case with me.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem just now by change the *android version to use when rendering layouts* to `API 19`, by default it's `API 20`:

[image]