# Not able to see graphical view in eclipse after adding <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView> in my android app since updated sdk

Tags: android, adview, graphical-layout-editor

Below is the error showing in Graphical View.

Exception raised during rendering:

```
com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

I have installed latest `SDK`.and `Google Play Service Library` is of revision 18. 
Is it related to jre or JDK version?

I am new to `Eclipse`.
I searched on `Google` but nothing helped. there is same question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331730/eclipse-graphical-layout-unable-to-display-adview) but no one has answered.
any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Nothing Issue Just Run Your Code

Comment: Thanks Naveen,actually it is difficult to develop an application because to test small change in XML, I need to run app and test on device. Please suggest the way to overcome this problem.

Comment: just comment that line and work on app when u publish app tha uncomment this line

Comment: we r also faceing this problem many time but slove this problem by using this to ads comment

Comment: I am also doing that as of now. but i want to remove this problem. Anyway if you get any solution then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are using Java JDK 1.6.

**You have to go to Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler  and set compiler to 1.7.
Ofcourse you must have Java JDK 1.7 installed. If you don't, install it and the problem will dissappear.**

At least that was the case with me.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am new to Linux. and once I tried to install jdk 1.7 and setting compiler to 1.7 but the problem was still there.